# How to make CTRL + '+' in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a button that increases the scaling so that if the user does not know about (CTRL +) or (CTRL -) they can use my buttons.

I tried the following
as an event for a button press.  I think there is a problem because it is a native browser call?
How to make this event described above happen.  Is there a browser call in jquery?

```
var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress");
ev.ctrlKey = false;
ev.which = 43;
$("document").trigger(ev);
```

Comment: $('body').animate({ 'zoom': 4.2 }, 100);

Comment: Doesn't work, just like the keys.  I put an alert in the function call just to make sure it was being called.  Maybe this is a restriction in firefox to call browser functions?

Comment: didn't tested in firefox. it's working in chrome